# Does completableFuture in Java 8 scale to multiple cores?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

Lets say I have a single thread that calls bunch of methods that return completablefuture and say I add all of them to a list and in the end I do `completablefutures.allof(list_size).join()`. Now does the futures in the list can scale to multiple cores? other words are the futures scheduled into multiple cores to take advantage of parallelism?

Comment: A `CompletableFuture` is unrelated to threads, let alone cores.

Comment: Hi I am not sure what you mean. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: A `CompletableFuture` is (more or less) just a holder for a value. It's up to you to decide which threads perform any operations on it.

Comment: please look at the answer below.

Answer (score 22):

`CompletableFuture` represents a task which is associated with some [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). If you did not specify executor explicitly (for example, you used [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier, Executor)`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), then common `ForkJoinPool` is used as executor. This pool could be obtained via [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) and by default it creates as many threads as many hardware threads your system has (usually number of cores, double it if your cores support hyperthreading). So in general, yes, if you use all defaults, then multiple cores will be used for your completable futures.

Comment: Why -1? This makes sense to me as long as it true?

Comment: A `CompletableFuture` is not associated with any `Executor`. Those are just helpful methods for scheduling work on some thread that will eventually complete a `CompletableFuture`. The future itself is unrelated to the work or to the thread(s) that complete(s) it. Don't frame it this way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so if I just use the way I specified in my question then its all  scheduled on a single thread ? and doesn't use multiple cores? please confirm even though it might be a redundant question

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so if I just use the way I specified in my question then its all  scheduled on a single thread ? and doesn't get scheduled on multiple cores? please confirm even though it might be a redundant question

Comment: @user1870400 There is no extra work scheduled. The futures in `list_size` have a dependent stage. All threads that are working on completing those futures have a chance of touching the returned `CompletableFuture`. Additionally, your calling thread gets potentially blocked on the `join`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you still don't seem to answer my question which is does all those futures gets scheduled on multiple threads and potentially multiple cores to take advantage of parallelism? Yes or No?

Comment: @user1870400 Your question is based on an incorrect assumption and therefore doesn't have a yes/no answer. A `CompletableFuture` doesn't _get scheduled_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you are just picking on my terminology. I am not sure how to explain it in your terms. I wrap some piece of code inside a future now does those pieces of code from all different futures gets scheduled on multiple threads while taking advantage of parallelism ? Yes or No?

Comment: @user1870400 _"I wrap some piece of code inside a future"_ No, a `CompletableFuture` is not a wrapper for code. There's code that creates the future, code that completes / cancels the future and code that waits for the result wrapped by the future. What you are most likely referring to is the code that completes the future. As long as you do not tell us how this code is invoked nobody can reliably answer your question.

Comment: @user1870400 Original Javadoc: _"A {@code Future} represents the result of an asynchronous computation."_ Note: The result, not the computation. Whether or not the computations run on different threads depends on you, i.e. on how you invoke them.

Answer (score 2):

CompletableFuture itself is not scheduled  to a thread (or core). Tasks are. To achieve parallelism, you need to create multiple tasks. If your methods which return CompletableFuture submit tasks like

> return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::calculate);

then multiple tasks are started.
If they just create CompletableFuture like

> return new CompletableFuture();

then no tasks are started and no parallelism present.

CompletableFuture objects created by CompletableFuture{handle, thenCombine, thenCompose, thenApply} are not connected to parallel tasks, so parallelism is not increased.

CompletableFuture objects created by CompletableFuture{handleAsync, thenCombineAsync, thenComposeAsync, thenApplyAsync} are connected to parallel tasks, but these tasks are executed strictly after the task corresponding to the `this` CompletableFuture object, so cannot increase parallelism.

Comment: Hi! the completable futures in my list call CompletableFuture.handle, CompletableFuture.thenCompose, CompletableFuture.thenApply. and all these are called by single thread so even in this case you seem to suggest that these will be executed in parallel? am I right?

Comment: @user1870400, the `CompletableFuture` methods you are referring to are all instance methods, so you must have created those instances in the first place. The parallelism will only depend on how you create them.

Answer (score 2):

Having a bunch of `CompletableFuture`s doesn't tell you anything about how they will be completed.

There are two kind of completions:

- Explicit, through [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-), [`complete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete-T-), [`completeExceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-), [`obtrudeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#obtrudeException-java.lang.Throwable-) and [`obtrudeValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#obtrudeValue-T-) on an instance, or by obtainng a future with the [`completedFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) static method
- Implicit, through executing a provided function, whether it returns normally or exceptionally, or through the completion of a previous future

  For instance:

  - [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) completes normally without running the provided function if the previous future completes normally
  - Every other chaining method, except for [`handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and their `*Async` variations, complete exceptionally without running the provided function if the previous future, or any of the previous futures in the combining (`*Both*`, `*Combine*` and `*Either*`) methods, complete exceptionally
  - Otherwise, the future completes when the provided function runs and completes either normally or exceptionally

If the futures you have were created without a function or they're not chained to another future, or in other words, if they don't have a function associated, then they will only complete explicitly, and as such it makes no sense to say if this kind of completable future **runs**, much less if they may use multiple threads.

On the other hand, if the futures have a function, it depends on how they were created:

- If they're all independent and use the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (or a cached thread pool or similar) as the executor, then they will probably run in parallel, possibly using as many active threads as the number of cores
- If they all have a dependency on each other (except for one) or if the executor is single-threaded, then they'll run one at a time
- Anything in between is valid, such as:

  - some futures may depend on each other, or on some other internal future you have no knowledge of
  - some futures may have been created with e.g. [a fixed thread pool executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) where you'll see a limited degree of concurrently running tasks

Invoking [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--) does not tell a future to start running, it just waits for it to complete.

So, to finally answer your question:

- If the future has a function associated, then it may already be running, it may or may not run its function depending on how it was chained and the completion of the previous future, and it may never run if it doesn't have a function or if it was completed before it had a chance to run its function
- The futures that are already running or that will run do so:

  - On the provided executor when chained with the `*Async` methods or when created with the `*Async` static methods that take an executor
  - On the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` when chained with the `*Async` methods or when created with the `*Async` static methods that don't take an executor
  - On the same thread as where the future they depend on is completed when chained without the `*Async` methods in case the future is not yet complete
  - On the current thread if the future they depend on is already completed when chained without the `*Async` methods

---

In my opinion, the explicit completion methods should have been segregated to a e.g. `CompletionSource` interface and have a e.g. `CompletableFutureSource` class that implements it and provides a future, much like .NET's relation between a `TaskCompletionSource` and its `Task`.

As things are now, most probably you can tamper with the completable futures you have by completing them in a way not originally intended.  For this reason, you should not use a `CompletableFuture` after you expose it publicly; it's your API user's `CompletableFuture` from then on.